# Why is devise sanitizer returning an empty hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-api

I am writing an API-only Rails 5 application and using the devise-jwt (and devise) gem for user authentication. I am trying to configure strong parameters in my custom registrations_controller. In `application_controller.rb`:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email])
end
```

And in `registrations_controller.rb`:

```
def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    resource.save
    #json response defined in application_controller.rb
    render_resource(resource)
end
```

This is the console's output when I make a POST request to the API via Postman:

`Parameters: {"first_name"=>"john", "last_name"=>"stones", "username"=>"johnstones", "email"=>"john@stones.com"}`

And this is the output from printing `params` to the console:

`<ActionController::Parameters {"first_name"=>"john", "last_name"=>"stones", "username"=>"johnstones", "email"=>"john@stones.com", "controller"=>"registrations", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>`

Despite the above when I do `devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_up)` I get an empty hash and my aforementioned POST throws the validation errors I set for having blank fields. Please help me figure out what I'm missing, thank you.

(Rails 5.2/Devise 4.2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Param `user` is missing in your params hash:

```
{"user": {"first_name"=>"john", "last_name"=>"stones", "username"=>"johnstones", "email"=>"john@stones.com"} }
```

Comment: Knew it was something small and obvious. Thank you.

Comment: Why `'user'` is needed?